# HoloLens 2 stops receiving UDP multicast packets when plugged into Windows -- Why and how do I always enable UDP multicast?

Tags: sockets, udp, multicast, hololens

I'm developing apps for the HoloLens 2, and my current project involves a server on LAN that hosts a multiplayer experience. I developed this auto discovery mechanism using UDP multicast so that HoloLens 2 clients can find what ip the server is on just by listening for these UDP multicast packets.

During testing, the battery was running low, so I plugged it into Windows, and all my UDP multicast stuff just stopped working on the HoloLens. I don't know why.

I'm sure there's a setting somewhere for it, but I don't know where or if it can even be changed.
I've encountered this issue before on Windows where I had to go into the network adapter settings for IPv4 and change the interface metric to `1` under advanced TCP/IPv4 settings. With that setting on `1`, Windows can receive UDP multicast packets, otherwise it does not.

Comment: What is your project type? UWP or Unity converted HL app? Besides, as a test, could you disable the Device Portal on your HoloLens first(Setting -> Update & Security -> For Developers) and try again? Do you see the same behavior? This will help to narrow down if device portal access over USB might be the potential reason causes this issue.

Comment: I'll keep this posted. Working on a couple different things.